# Android pathshape to draw a dynamic line

Tags: android

Could anyone give me an example to use PathShape to draw something?
And could it used for drawing dynamic line such a line graph diagram??

Thanks for Your Help.

Comment: what is the exact purpose of displaying / drawing the line. can you please elaborate?

Comment: I plan to used it for drawing a dynamic line graph chart diagram. So it can form like an opened polygon (polyline). Is it possible?

Comment: yeh I think it is possible by using Paint i.e  android.graphics.Paint and android.graphics.Path.

Comment: would you like to give a program example? Thanks anyway

Comment: no no you can just use canvas & build further points & path on it.

Comment: @abdurrahman: did you make it to draw such animated PathShape? If so, how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL ES you can use glDrawArrays in GL_LINES mode. It is exactly like using draw Canvas, but is considerably faster and portable too.  Here is the snippet of code I used to draw a 3D triangle using lines.

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, 2, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);
```

I would go through this tutorial just to learn about shapes in 3D space. [3D Tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-vi,436.html)